# Django session is not deleted after logout

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-sessions

I recently discovered that the logout functionality of my Django app seems to be broken. I believe it worked in the past, but I cannot figure out why it is not working now.

That's my setup:

index.html:

```
...
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <a style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" href="{% url 'auth_logout' %}">Logout</a>
{% else %}
    <a style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" href="{% url 'auth_login' %}">Login</a>
{% endif %}
...
```

urls.py:

```
...
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
...

urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', auth_views.logout, name='auth_logout'),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', auth_views.login, name='auth_login'),
    ...
]
```

Templates:

login.html:

```
{% extends 'simple_logo_base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            {% if next %}
                <form action="/accounts/login/?next={{next}}" method="post" >
            {%else%}
                <form action="/accounts/login/" method="post" >
            {% endif %}
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button type="submit">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

logout.html:

```
{% extends 'simple_logo_base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h2 class="text-center">Logged out</h2>
{% endblock %}
```

Where "simple_logo_base.html" is just the plain html structure with a div containing a logo.

The problem:
The logging in works perfectly fine. If I try to access the restricted index.html page, I am redirected to the login page, can login and can access the restricted page.

Once I am logged in and I click on the "Logout" button (see above) I am also redirected to the logout.html page, however, I can still go back to the index.html and I am still logged in.

I therefore had a look at the "django_sessions" table in the database and noticed that the session is never deleted. If I manually delete it, then I am redirected to the login page again when accessing the index.html.

What am I doing wrong? What could be the issue?

I recently upgraded to Django 1.10 and also added the Caching framework to my project. Could it be related to any of these changes?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem meanwhile. However, I am not sure what the exact problem was. If anyone else experiences similar issues, here are the things I have tried (and that apparently solved the issue for me):

- Reset all auth-related url configs
- Use @vary_on_cookie decorator to cache pages based on session
- Clear all caches and sessions

I think the problem was mainly related to the caching. When using the @cache_page decorator, the caching is only based on the URL that is requested. Therefore, every user received the same cached page, even if he was logged out already. However, this does not explain why the session was not deleted when logging out. So maybe something else was the main issue here.